# How to create an alias name for a model in Rails Active Records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a model `Author`. I want to assign each `Article` an `Author`, but not all authors are `AdminUser` (my other model). How could I set up the model associations so that **every article must have an author but not every author has to have admin privileges?**

And if I can `@article.author` it will return the author even if it is an AdminUser

```
class Author  < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name
  has_many :articles

end

class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base

  attr_accessor :first_name, :last_name, #...a bunch of authentication params, passwords, salt, etc

  has_many :articles

end
```

What I would prefer is not have to ever have to say @article.admin_user.. I want it always to say @article.author.. But I want to be able to ask @admin_user.articles.

Comment: AdminUser's can be an Author but not always the other way around.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a couple approaches.

1. Use Single Table Inheritance (STI)

   ```
   class User < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :articles
   end

   class Author < User
   end

   class AdminUser < User
   end

   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :user
   end
   ```

   This will require the `users` table to have all attributes used by all descendants, and will require a `type` column so an `AdminUser` record remembers its an `AdminUser`
2. Use a polymorphic association

   ```
   class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :articles, as: :owner
   end

   class AdminUser < ActiveRecord::Base
     has_many :articles, as: :owner
   end

   class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :owner, polymorphic: true
   end
   ```

   This requires that `articles` has both `owner_id` and `owner_type` (String) columns.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought, instead of making an AdminUser class, maybe rolling that functionality into a module, mix-in, or gem. Article and Author make perfect sense as classes. However, it seems you want authors to have admin functionality, but only some of the time. Do something like this maybe:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Only include properties if this particular author should have them
  if self.is_admin?
    has_admin_functions
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a single user class with author and admin flags?